# Is it possible to start service/activity when connect to ble device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am develop a android application with BLE.

My bluetooth device can be searched by bluetooth scanning of android.

And my application can connect with the bluetooth device by `connectGatt()`

When my application is running(even there's only foreground service running), the connection is continue. (I use `autoConnect=true`)

But even if my application is not running, I hope Android OS will try to connect if it finds my Bluetooth device and start foreground service or activity of my application.

is that possible?

In the window of bluetooth device list found by Android OS, I can find my bluetooth device. But if i touch it, they say "an app is needed to use this device" right now.

Please tell me how to let Android OS try to connect with my bluetooth device even if my application is running or not.

Comment: What do you mean? If you have a foreground service the service keeps running even if the app is not on foreground, you should display a notification to get aware of when the service is running.

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi Sorry I am not good at English. I want to make my bluetooth device to be like a Airpot which is connected not in application but Android OS. And i want start my application when connected if it was not running including foreground service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Android will not start an application (a new process) due to a BLE connection has been established. A connectGatt attempt is only valid as long as the app process runs.

You can however scan for devices without the app running, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner#startScan(java.util.List%3Candroid.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter%3E,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings,%20android.app.PendingIntent).

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answer! I gonna find something different way. And oh, I saw the answer you wrote in another question about "Auto/DirectConnection". It was very helpful for me. Thank you.